# Field-like implementation of events

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Recently I've tried to understand the field-like implementation of events. MSIL code is not clear enough, therefore I used [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgrgzglgOwOYAIDKBPGAXApgWwG4BYAKAAcoAjAGzgGMV6aBDGGFAYRQG8yUBKSrQYoAbgHs4wFAFkAFAEpe/QWrQT8uXGNwJsAOgCSCSQGtcSkqTUBfVQOF1GOvdhQBBetjgSE6TW1dfUIUBxQcFh9GSWk5FkQlcL4bNUExFgAnJhQAXhQEXAB3Litw+1IKoA) to see c# code without syntactic sugar, and received this:

```
private Action m_Someevent;

public event Action Someevent
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    add
    {
        Action action = this.m_Someevent;
        Action action2;
        do
        {
            action2 = action;
            Action value2 = (Action)Delegate.Combine(action2, value);
            action = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.m_Someevent, value2, action2);
        }
        while ((object)action != action2);
    }
    [CompilerGenerated]
    remove
    {
        Action action = this.m_Someevent;
        Action action2;
        do
        {
            action2 = action;
            Action value2 = (Action)Delegate.Remove(action2, value);
            action = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref this.m_Someevent, value2, action2);
        }
        while ((object)action != action2);
    }
}
```

What is `do while`cycle used for? I've debugged many cases of subscription, and always cycle passes only once. I had an idea, that it used for iteration on `invocattionlist` but it was wrong.

Comment: Thread-safety is the concern here.  Delegate objects are immutable to ensure they are atomic, adding or removing an event handler requires creating a new object.  So this is a read-modify-write operation, they are never safe in threaded code.  The loop ensures that another thread didn't sneak ahead and wrote its own object, causing the un/subscribe attempt of one of the threads to be lost.  This *used* to be done differently, old C# compilers generated code that used [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)].  That was not reliable enough.

Comment: Fwiw, if you write your own add/remove accessors then you often skip this.  Knowing that such a race bug is not a real problem, it very rarely is.  But the C# compiler can't know so must assume the worst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event adds and removes are designed to atomic, even in the face of multithreaded situations.  You should be able to subscribe to a given event from two threads and be sure that both get added.

This is accomplished by reading the value of the underlying field, combining the delegate with the delegate to add, trying to assign it back to the field, and only moving on if the value in the field when you assign it back is the value that was in there originally, before you added yours.  In effect, it's checking if the underlying field changed while you were doing the work in the earlier lines of code.  If it had, it tries again, until nothing else happened between the fetching and setting of the field.

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov The purpose is making event adds and removes logically atomic from any outside observer.  Whether that results in a properly thread safe application depends on how the callers use it.

Comment: another words, `dowhile` is for waiting that another thread ends its manupulations with `m_Someevent` field. Nice

Comment: @FonyFazoulyanov No, it's not waiting for anything. It's attempting to make a change, and redoing it if it didn't work correctly.  It never waits on anything else, it just stays in the busy loop, trying again and again, until it works.